# C++ Search for a unique word and assign it a number

Tags: c++, search, count

I am looking at various examples of reading an input file and counting the occurrences of a word. Then give it a variable to count.

Lets say we have an input file and you want to look for how many times the word "account" or word "like" shows up and give it the variable "1.2". So when you find the word, count how many times it occurs and then times it by 1.2 .

How would you go about doing this?

EDIT: This is the only way I know how. However, this pre-searches the word versus letting the user search it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int option=0; //option number
    ifstream inputFile;
    string filename;

    cout << "Welcome\n" << endl;

    //Getting the input file
    cout << "Enter input data file name:";
    cin >> filename;
    cout << endl;

    fin.open(filename.c_str()); // change to C-string

    if (!inputFile) {// makes sure file exist
            cout << "Unable to open " << filename << endl;
            cin.get();
            return 1;
            }

    do {
            cout << "5- Count frequency of the following three words individually: I, like, is" << endl;

            cout << "6 - To quit";
            cout << endl;
            cin >> option;

            int iWord = 0;
            int likeWord = 0;
            int isWord = 0;

             if (option == 5) {
                    string word;
                    do {
                            inputFile >> word;
                            if (word == "I") iWord++;
                            else if (word== "like") likeWord++;
                            else if (word == "is") isWord++;
                            }while (inputFile.good());
                    cout << "The word I is repeated " << iWord << " times" << endl;
                    cout << "The word is has been repeated " << isWord << " times" << endl;
                    cout << "The word like is repeated " << likeWord << " times" << endl << endl;
                    }
            inputFile.clear(); // clear fail bit or seekg won't work!
            inputFile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    }while (option != 6);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is trivially achievable using any standard map (ordered or unordered, but I would recc `std::unordered_map<std::string,unsigned int>`) and a simple stream iteration. It is considerably more complex to normalize the words (case, punctuation stripping) before mapping than it is to maintain the counts within the map. You've given no information whether that is needed or not given the lack of any formal description of your input file, so without further detail, that's about all I can suggest. Once the map is built, you can search for *any* word and simply report its frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most efficient way (especially for one word), but maybe this could give you direction:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>

void tokenize( const std::string & line, std::unordered_map< std::string, size_t > & map_count )
{
    for( std::string::size_type pos_start = 0, pos_end = 0; ( pos_end != std::string::npos ) && ( pos_start = line.find_first_of( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", pos_end ) ) != std::string::npos; )
    {
         pos_end = line.find_first_not_of( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", pos_start );
         std::string current_word = ( pos_end == std::string::npos ) ? line.substr( pos_start ) : line.substr( pos_start, pos_end - pos_start );
         std::unordered_map< std::string, size_t >::iterator iter( map_count.find( current_word ) );
         if( iter == map_count.end() )
             map_count.insert( std::pair< std::string, size_t >( current_word, 1 ) );
         else
             ++( iter->second );
    }
}

void countWordsInFile( const std::string & filename, std::unordered_map< std::string, size_t > & map_count )
{
    std::ifstream in( filename );
    std::string line;
    size_t count = 0;
    if( in.is_open() )
        while( std::getline( in, line ).good() )
            tokenize( line, map_count );
}

double countAndWeigh( const std::string & filename, const std::string & word, double weight )
{
    std::unordered_map< std::string, size_t > map_count;
    countWordsInFile( filename, map_count );
    std::unordered_map< std::string, size_t >::const_iterator iter( map_count.find( word ) );
    return ( iter != map_count.end() ) ? iter->second * weight : 0;
}  


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    if( argc == 4 )
        std::cout << countAndWeigh( argv[1], argv[2], strtod( argv[3], nullptr ) ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have never seen this before. I will have to look into it and play with your example. Thanks for sharing.